# what is the better way to loop this problem?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int arr[9][9];
int i = 0, x = 10;

for (int i = 0, j = 0; j <= 8; j++) {
    x++;
    arr[i][j] = x;
}
for (int j = 8, i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    x++;
    arr[i][j] = x;
}
for (int i = 8, j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {
    x++;
    arr[i][j] = x;
}
for (int j = 0, i = 7; i >= 1; i--) {
    x++;
    arr[i][j] = x;
}

for (int i = 1, j = 1; j <= 7; j++) {
    x++;
    arr[i][j] = x;
}
for (int j = 7, i = 2; i <= 7; i++) {
    x++;
    arr[i][j] = x;
}
for (int i = 7, j = 6; j >= 1; j--) {
    x++;
    arr[i][j] = x;
}
for (int j = 1, i = 6; i >= 2; i--) {
    x++;
    arr[i][j] = x;
}
...
arr[4][4] = x + 1;


for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 8; j++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
}
getch();
}
```

so I have this program, and I know you can loop it but how ? been sitting for an hour thinking and nothing came to my mind. By the way, the task is to append a matrix like on picture. Does anyone know to do it ? Maybe use some complex for loop[image]

Comment: 4 variables to keep track of the upper and lower boundaries for x and y directions.  One big loop until they cross, containing 4 for loops (one per side).  After each line along one side, adjust the boundary for that side.

Comment: what's the point for using "variables" for constants in the loops?

Comment: You don't need *any* `for` loops, just a while loop. Turn left whenever hitting the edge or an already filled position.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala it needs to turn right, isn`t it ? But how do I do it ?

Comment: Though it's *possible* to use a single `while` loop and no `for`s, keep in mind that that `while` would do many more iterations than any single `for` would have, and would need to test the movement direction and choose it's behaviour accordingly on every iteration.  It's not objectively better than using `for` loops.

Comment: @СтепанБандера yes ;)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala but how to turn ?)

Comment: @СтепанБандера one easy way is to consider the current coordinates and current "delta/velocity" as complex numbers; and turning right is multiplying the velocity by `-i`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala sorry, I dont really know whats a complex number is (( is there an easier way ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
int arr[9][9] = {0};
int x = 0, i = 0, j = 0, vi = 0, vj = 1;

do {
    ++x;
    arr[i][j] = x;

    {
        int ii = i+vi;
        int jj = j+vj;
        if (ii < 0 || ii >= 9 || jj < 0 || jj >= 9 || arr[ii][jj] != 0) {
            if (vi != 0) {
                vj = -vi;
                vi = 0;
            } else {
                vi = vj;
                vj = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    i = i+vi;
    j = j+vj;
} while (arr[i][j] == 0);
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71a4f229bd0f1319)

Here's another way:

```
int arr[9][9] = {0};
int x = 0, i = 0, j = 0, vi = 0, vj = 1, lk = 8;

while (lk > 0) {
    for (int k = 0; k < lk; ++k) {
        ++x;
        arr[i][j] = x;
        i += vi;
        j += vj;
    }

    vi = vj;
    vj = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < lk; ++k) {
        ++x;
        arr[i][j] = x;
        i += vi;
        j += vj;
    }

    vj = -vi;
    vi = 0;

    if (vj > 0) {
        ++i;
        ++j;
        lk -= 2;
    }
}

arr[9/2][9/2] = x+1; // Only if odd dimensions
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ac256d4f8201be7)

And here is yet another:

```
int arr[9][9] = {0};
int i = 0, lk = 8, x = 1;

while (lk > 0) {
    for (int k = 0; k < lk; ++k) {
        arr[i][i+k] = x + k;
        arr[i+k][lk+i] = x + lk + k;
        arr[lk+i][lk+i-k] = x + 2*lk + k;
        arr[lk+i-k][i] = x + 3*lk + k;
    }

    x += 4*lk;
    lk -= 2;
    ++i;
}

arr[9/2][9/2] = x; // Only if odd dimensions
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87f84a1e782ddc58)

Comment: it works perfectly ! but can you explain a bit what `vi` `vj` `ii` `jj` means ?

Comment: `vi` and `vj` tell where you are currently going (think of it as a velocity vector); they are the increments for `i` and `j`. `ii` and `jj` are just temporaries.

Comment: so `vi` and `vj` are current positions and they increment `i` and `j` ?

Comment: @kfx Well, you can very well put it in functions with better names and also pass the matrix size, but I'm not going to do that for you.

Comment: @СтепанБандера `i` and `j` are positions. `vi` and `vj` are increments.

Comment: it is , I didnt know that you cant accept 2 answers :)

Comment: @Nelfeal whats `lk` in third code ? its number of rows ?

Comment: The third code builds the matrix "ring by ring", with the first ring containing all the values on the four edges. `lk` is the width of the current ring, minus one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the "straight forward" option with `for` loops:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5

int main(void) {
    int i,j,dim;
    int matrix[N][N];

    // init and print the matrix
    for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j< N; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = i*N + j;
            printf("%2d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n");

    // perform spiral print
    for (dim = 0; dim < (N+1)/2; dim++)
    {
        // set initial i and go till the "last column"
        i = dim;
        for (j = dim; j < N - dim; j++)
        {
            printf("%2d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        // bring back i and j to the proper coordinate
        // and move down to the "last row"
        j--;i++;
        for (; i < N - dim; i++)
        {
            printf("%2d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        // bring back i and j to the proper coordinate
        // and move back to the "first column"
        i--;j--;
        for (; j >= dim; j--)
        {
            printf("%2d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        // bring back i and j to the proper coordinate
        // and move up to the "first row"
        j++;i--;
        for (; i > dim; i--)
        {
            printf("%2d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output, as can be seen [here](https://ideone.com/UogBnc) is

```
 0  1  2  3  4 
 5  6  7  8  9 
10 11 12 13 14 
15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 

 0  1  2  3  4 
 9 14 19 24 
23 22 21 20 
15 10  5 
 6  7  8 
13 18 
17 16 
11 
12
```

==========================================================================

Looks like I misunderstood the question but the step from "printing" clockwise to "setting" clockwise is really small. Here is the setting flow:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 5

int main(void) {
    int i,j,dim, val = 1;
    int matrix[N][N];

    // perform spiral print
    for (dim = 0; dim < (N+1)/2; dim++)
    {
        // set initial i and go till the "last column"
        i = dim;
        for (j = dim; j < N - dim; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = val++;
        }

        // bring back i and j to the proper coordinate
        // and move down to the "last row"
        j--;i++;
        for (; i < N - dim; i++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = val++;
        }

        // bring back i and j to the proper coordinate
        // and move back to the "first column"
        i--;j--;
        for (; j >= dim; j--)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = val++;
        }

        // bring back i and j to the proper coordinate
        // and move up to the "first row"
        j++;i--;
        for (; i > dim; i--)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = val++;
        }
    }

    // print the matrix
    for (i=0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j< N; j++)
        {
            printf("%2d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output as shown [here](https://ideone.com/vytnxL) is

```
 1  2  3  4  5 
16 17 18 19  6 
15 24 25 20  7 
14 23 22 21  8 
13 12 11 10  9
```

Comment: it works like this ------> <------, but it needs to do it clockwise :(

Comment: @СтепанБандераIt works clockwise: (right) 0-->4, (down) 9-->24, (left) 23-->20, (up) 15-->5, etc.

Comment: @СтепанБандера The first print that you see is just the matrix initialization, then you see the "clockwise" print

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with the question since `matrix` only contains what's shown in the first output, and the second output is pretty much useless.

Comment: @Nelfeal the question was how to loop the matrix in the clockwise manner. The first print shows the matrix content in the usual manner, then the same content is printed in the clockwise manner. That's all.

Comment: @Nelfeal I feel sorry for you that you answer "accept" was reverted. But downvote here is **not** reasonable.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the code posted in the question? It clearly shows the intent: modifying the matrix so that it contains increasing values in a spiral path, not printing arbitrary values by following a spiral path.

Comment: @NelfealLooks like I misunderstood the question... but the step from the "print" flow to "set" flow is really tiny.

Comment: @СтепанБандера Hopefully this time I added the answer as you meant it (see the bottom part).

Comment: yes, now it working correctly, thanks for your time ! and thanks for comments to make code more understandable :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution. Using an "object" `struct strangeite_s` (from strange ite-rator). It allows ease reusing on different arrays and probably could be even rescaled to support n-dimensional arrays.
The `strangeite` is initialized using `_init` function with specified dimensions sizes of an 2d array. Each time `_loop` is evaluated, the `x` and `y` positions are updated and the condition for loop end is checked (and returned). The `_inc` function should be called on each increment of the iterator.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct strangeite_s {
    size_t steplen[2];
    size_t idx[2];
    size_t cursteplen;
    int direction;
};

void strangeite_init(struct strangeite_s *t, size_t max_x, size_t max_y)
{
    assert(t != NULL);
    t->steplen[0] = max_y;
    t->steplen[1] = max_x;
    memset(t->idx, 0, sizeof(t->idx));
    t->direction = 0;
    t->cursteplen = t->steplen[0];
}

bool strangeite_loop(const struct strangeite_s *t, size_t *x, size_t *y)
{
    if (x) *x = t->idx[0];
    if (y) *y = t->idx[1];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(t->steplen)/sizeof(t->steplen[0]); ++i) {
        if (t->steplen[i] == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void strangeite_inc(struct strangeite_s *t)
{
    if (t->cursteplen != 1) {
        --t->cursteplen;
    } else {
        t->direction = ++t->direction % (2 * 2);
        t->cursteplen = --t->steplen[t->direction % 2];
    }
    const size_t idx_to_change = t->direction % 2;
    t->idx[idx_to_change] = t->idx[idx_to_change] + ( t->direction < 2 ? +1 : -1 );
}

int main()
{
    int var[5][5];

    struct strangeite_s  i;
    strangeite_init(&i, 5, 5);
    int idx = 0;
    for (size_t x, y; strangeite_loop(&i, &x, &y); strangeite_inc(&i)) {
        var[y][x] = ++idx; 
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
            printf("%d ", var[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
1 2 3 4 5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
16 17 18 19 6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
15 24 25 20 7                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
14 23 22 21 8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
13 12 11 10 9
```

Live version at [onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/ryEUsLITm).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to deterministically compute any one entry in the array `A_{i,j}` as a function only given the array size `N`, and `i`, `j`, in `O(1)`, on-line, without any state, noticing the radius is a geometric progression. The space requirement is `O(1)` since one doesn't actually need the array to store the values; we can scan the array sequentially. However, like ray-tracing, it probably is slower, (up to a constant, it's still `O(N^2)`.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* N: The size of the (simulated) array. */
#define N (16)

/* i, j: The array indices, as if, a[i][j]. */
static int a(const int i, const int j) {
    /* (x,y) translation of (i,-j) to the centre, scaled up 2x for int math. */
    const int x = 2 * i + 1 - N, y = -2 * j - 1 + N;
    /* Geometric series and an offset +fiddling to get the directionality. */
    return N*N - ((x < -y) ?
        (-x > -y) ? (x+1)*(x+1) - (y+x)/2 - 1: y*y + (x+y)/2 :
        (x > y) ? x*x + (x+y)/2 : (y+1)*y + (-x+y)/2);
}

int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    for(j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            printf("%3d ", a(i, j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```